# Comparing two arrays in unit test throwing a AssertFailedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm writing an unit tests for ready code and I'm receiving an unexpected AssertFailedException trying to run one of the test. Here is he:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestPositionGetter()
    {
        testPlayer.Position = new int[] { 1, 3 };
        int[] expectedPosition = testPlayer.Position;
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedPosition, testPlayer.Position);
    }
```

And here is the Position property in the Player class that I'm trying to test:

```
public int[] Position
    {
        get
        {
            return new int[] { this.PositionX, this.PositionY };
        }
        set
        {
            this.PositionX = value[0];
            this.PositionY = value[1];
        }
    }
```

Debugging the test, in local variables window player.Position and expectedPosition are looking similar but the test is still failing. I'm afraid the problem is coming from references.

Comment: can you post your error ?

Comment: Since there is already a good answer, I would like to suggest grabbing FluentAssertions as it has a ton of really nice methods for working with IEnumerable objects and other objects in general.

Comment: The anwer of @Anri was correct, the test passed.

Answer (score 43):

You are comparing different instances of an `int[]`. `Assert.AreEqual` compares by reference. Try `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`.

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedPosition, testPlayer.Position);
```

This will compare array elements.

Also, your `Position` property smells like bad design. Do you really have to create new array every time you get a value?

Comment: I have no idea, I just have to write the tests. But tell me what's your idea.

Comment: Well, I would need to see the whole class, but from what is pasted here - you should create `private int[] _position;` in that class and use it in your getter and setter instead of creating new array every time.

Comment: if you pass a private array reference to a caller as result of a property getter, they can keep the reference to it and change values in it / cause hard to find bugs